# Not able to get message_tags of type "user"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, restfb

I'm using RestFB to get the data for FB comments, in particular the message_tags. It seems to work fine when the type of the message_tag is a "page", but I get an empty list when the type = "user".
Here is the FB commend id where this happens: 10156566664184478_10156576298439478
I'm using:

List msgtaglist = Comment.getMessageTags();

to get the list of MessageTag's. 
But it returns an empty list for the comment above, although the FB Graph Explorer shows there is a message tag.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Reinaldo

Comment: Unless you want to debug into the RestFB code base yourself to see where it goes wrong, I'd say your best option is to report a bug with the people who make it (probably in form of an issue report on github.)

Comment: Thanks. I've done that now and the problem is being debugged.

Comment: I add the link to the bug report on github here, so someone with a similar problem can jump right into it: https://github.com/restfb/restfb/issues/768